# Prove that polynomial $x^{2n}-nx^{n+1} +nx^{n-1}-1$ has root $1$ with multiplicity $3$.

Tags: calculus

Prove that polynomial $x^{2n}-nx^{n+1} +nx^{n-1}-1$ has root $1$ with multiplicity $3$.

I am thinking about using $Horner's$ $method$ but don't know how.

Comment: Try dividing it by $(x-1)^3$. You want to show that the quotient doesn’t have $1$ as a root and that the remainder is $0$.

Comment: can't  you use that 1 is a root of  second deriverate of this polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's $P(x) = x^{2n}-nx^{n+1} +nx^{n-1}-1$, we have

$$P'(x) = 2nx^{2n-1}-n(n+1)x^{n}+(n+1)nx^{n-2}$$

$$P''(x) = 2nx^{2n-1}x^{2n-2}-n^2(n+1)x^{n-1}+(n-2)(n-1)nx^{n-3}$$

As $$P(1) = 0$$
$$P'(1) = 0$$
$$P''(1) = 0$$

Then $P(x)$ has root 1 with multiplicity 3

PS: If the OP wants to prove that $P(x)$ has root 1 with multiplicity exactly 3, it suffices to calculate $P'''(x)$ and prove that $P'''(1)  \ne 0$

Comment: You have only shown that the multiplicity is at least $3$.

Comment: @Tavish That might be enough. It's a semantic issue whether they mean _exactly_ $3$, or if a quadruple root counts as a triple. I personally think this is enough.

Comment: @Arthur The question has implicitly stated exactly $3$. I mean, it literally says ‘multiplicity $3$‘.

Comment: @Tavish You're right. Triple root carries different connotations to root of multiplicity $3$.

Answer (score -1):

$$x^{2n}-nx^{n+1} +nx^{n-1}-1$$
$$ x^{2n}-1 +nx^{n-1}-n^{n+1}$$
$$(  x^{2n}-1) + (nx^{n-1}-n^{n+1})$$
$$(x-1)(x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}+\dots +x+1) + nx^{n-1}( 1-x^2)$$
$$(x-1)(x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}+\dots +x+1) - nx^{n-1}( x+1)(x-1)$$
$$(x-1)(x^{2n-1}+x^{2n-2}+\dots +x+1 - nx^{n-1}( x+1) )$$

Comment: This does not really help. You showed that $1$ is a root with multiplicity at least $1$. But this can be shown be substituting $x=1$ directly into the polynomial.